# Datagridviewtextboxcolumn length and text?

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.NET

Am Using a textbox in Datagridview

Code for adding a textbox in DataGridview

```
Dim ti As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(ti)
```

Text box Maximum size should be 5. Text box should display "  :  "

How to set like this.

Need  vb.net code Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'Text box should display ":"' ? Are you wanting to provide a mask or something? Anyway, here's how to the maximum size bit:

```
    Dim ti = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    ti.DataPropertyName = "TODO"
    ti.Name = "TODO"
    ti.HeaderText = "TODO"
    ti.MaxInputLength = 5
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumnDataGridView1.Columns.Add(ti)
```